# How about the Fourier transform of the constant zero?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis

But how to get the Fourier transform of the zero? It seems

$$\hat{0}(x)=\int_{R} 0 e^{-2\pi i xy} dy=0$$

Comment: No, that integral is $0$.

Comment: I believe $\int_E 0 \; d\mu$ is necessarily $0$ for any set $E$ and any measure $\mu$.

Comment: What???????????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't you have
$$
\hat{0}(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} 0 e^{-2\pi i xy} dy = \int_{\mathbb{R}} 0 dy = 0
$$

Comment: So the inverse Fourier transform of zero is still zero?

Comment: @BobOakley yes, correct